# Linked list addition of two minimum at last node like tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I have switched to c# from c++. I am under a situation where i am using linked list which contains nodes as follows : (which is sorted in increasing order)

```
1->1->1->44->46->48->49->50->null
```

What i have to do is :

(1)Add the first two nodes.
(2)Put the some obtained at the last node.
So, here after first addition the LList will be :(1+1=2)

```
1->1->1->44->46->48->49->50->2->null
```

(3)Again add the two minimum nodes and put the sum at last node(**But don't add the nodes which are already added**).

(4) This time the two minimum are 1 and 2 because "1" and "1"(the first two) are already added. LList now becomes :

```
 1->1->1->44->46->48->49->50->2->3->null
```

(5) Now two minimum are 3 and 44 ,so

```
1->1->1->44->46->48->49->50->2->3->47->null
```

(6) Now two minimum are 46 and 47(see at last we have 47 which second smallest) , so
    1->1->1->44->46->48->49->50->2->3->47->93->null
(7) Now 48 and 49, so

```
1->1->1->44->46->48->49->50->2->3->47->93->97->null
```

(8) next minimums are "50" and "93" are left so,

```
1->1->1->44->46->48->49->50->2->3->47->93->97->143->null
```

(9) Finally:
97 and 143 are left, so

```
 1->1->1->44->46->48->49->50->2->3->47->93->97->143->240->null
```

There is only one element left(240) so stop here.

Could some one please help me in making it's algorithm ? Thanks

My Idea: to implement this algorithm is : here "freq" contains the value and left and right are like tree left and right.

```
    while (front != rear) 
    {
         if (counter == 0) 
        { 
             Console.WriteLine("check1");
            temp = new Node();
            temp.freq = front.freq + front.next.freq;
            front.is_processed = 1;
            front.next.is_processed = 1;
            temp.is_processed = 0;
            temp.left = front;
            temp.right = front.next;
            temp.next = null;
            rear.next = temp;
            front = front.next.next;
            rear = rear.next;
            remaining = count_remaining();
            if (remaining == 1) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        if (rear.freq.Equals(front.freq)) 
        {
             Console.WriteLine("check2");
            temp = new Node();
            temp.freq = front.freq + rear.freq;
            rear.is_processed = 1;
            front.is_processed = 1;
            temp.is_processed = 0;
            temp.left = front;
            temp.right = rear;
            temp.next = null;
            rear.next = temp;
            rear = rear.next;
            remaining = count_remaining();
            if (remaining == 1) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rear.freq < front.freq) 
        {
           Console.WriteLine("check3");
            Node pmin1 = null;
            Node pmin2 = null;
            front_rear(ref pmin1, ref pmin2);
            temp = new Node();
            temp.freq = pmin1.freq + pmin2.freq;
            pmin1.is_processed = 1;
            pmin2.is_processed = 1;
            temp.is_processed = 0;
            temp.left = pmin2;
            temp.right = pmin1;
            temp.next = null;
            rear.next = temp;
             rear = rear.next;
            remaining = count_remaining();
            if (remaining == 1) 
            {
                break;
            }                   
        }   

        if (rear.freq > front.freq)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("check4");
            Node pmin1 = null;
            Node pmin2 = null;
            front_rear(ref pmin1, ref pmin2);
            temp = new Node();
            temp.freq = pmin1.freq + pmin2.freq;
            pmin1.is_processed = 1;
            pmin2.is_processed = 1;
            temp.is_processed = 0;
            temp.left = pmin2;
            temp.right = pmin1;
            temp.next = null;
            rear.next = temp;
            rear = rear.next;
            remaining = count_remaining();
            if (remaining == 1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }            
        counter++;
    }
```

But surprisingly the it prints : (it not at all go to "check3" which is `if (rear.freq < front.freq)` and you can see my step5 above is at this condition but don't print `check3` )

```
check1
check4
check4
check4
check4
check4
check4
```

**Why it is just going in condition `if (rear.freq > front.freq)`  ?** (It's actualy a tree using linked list) where parent node is the sum of two minimum nodes.

Comment: the steps that you've given us show that you actually already know the algorithm.  What are you actually having trouble with?

Comment: are you having trouble determining which nodes that you've already summed?  are you having trouble reading from or writing to the linked list?  are you having trouble creating nodes?  Are you having trouble adding 2 numbers together?

Comment: The algorithm you have described is correct. Are you having trouble implementing it in C# ?

Comment: @Thanks all i have edited the code

Comment: @Dukeling There is no use of a heap. The problem can be solved in linear time. See that the original linkedlist is sorted.

Comment: @NikunjBanka Oh, right, I didn't see that.

Comment: why do your nodes have a `left`, `right`, **and** a `next`?  is this some sort of 2-d list?

Comment: @Yes it's like a tree. Huffman tree do the same additions of node but i just sort only once and the input to this algo is a sorted lInked list.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is really sloppy, so I'll give you a basic framework to use

```
Node first = FindLowestUnprocessedNode();
Node second = FindLowestUnprocessedNode();

while(first != null && second != null)
{

    Node sumNode = new Node(first, second)

    AddToEndOfList(sumNode);  

    Node first = FindLowestUnprocessedNode();
    Node second = FindLowestUnprocessedNode();
}
```

Here are some functions for you to make yourself.  These shouldn't be too hard

- `FindLowestUnprocessedNode(...)`:  finds the lowest unprocessed node and marks it as processed.  if all the nodes are processed, it returns `null`.  You might find that you want to add extra parameters to this method.
- `Node(Node first, Node second)`:  add this constructor to your `Node` class.  It should initialize the node to have `first` to the left and `second` to the right, and it's `freq` should be the sum of `first.freq` and `second.freq`.
- `AddToEndOfList(Node newNode);`:  adds the node to the end of your list.

Please note that these are only abstract place-holder methods you can and probably should add extra parameters to them, or make them into instance methods if you think that it would help you out.